# how to handle error messages in view model using mvvm swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm

when we have login username and password those details are sent to the view model if any error occurs how to handle in view model itself with out sending error data to the view controller.

Comment: Please share code.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer dealing error in data source or data repository layer

In model layer,  that shall clarify immediately and establish error handling logic,  or you can establish object of exception to store the error

For example:

Declare error with enum

```
enum MockServicesError: Error {
    /// Server response object with error
    case serverResponseErrorWith(message: String)
    /// Server response object is nil
    case withoutResponseObject
    /// Fatel Error with message
    case fatelErrorWith(message: String)
    /// Fatel Error
    case fatelError
}
```

Preliminary in model layer

```
protocol DataRepositoryProtocol {
    func queryMockServices(_ parameter: MockParameter?, completion: @escaping((Result<String?, MockServicesError>) -> ()))
}

final class DataRepositoryManager: DataRepositoryProtocol {
    
    func queryMockServices(_ parameter: MockParameter?, completion: @escaping((Result<String?, MockServicesError>) -> ())) {
        guard
            let dataNo1 = parameter?.dataNO1,
            let dataNo2 = parameter?.dataNO2,
            let dataNo3 = parameter?.dataNO3,
            let request = Factory.fetchesMockRequest(dataNo1, dataNo2, dataNo3)
            else { return }
        
        MockWebAPI.send(request) { (response, error) in
            if let err = error {
                completion(.failure(MockServicesError.fatelErrorWith(message: err.localizedDescription)))
            } else {
                guard let response = response as? MockResponse else { return completion(.failure(MockServicesError.fatelError)) }
                if let statusCode = response.statusCode, statusCode == "0" {
                    guard let dataString = response.dataString else { return completion(.failure(MockServicesError.withoutResponseObject)) }
                    completion(.success(dataString))
                } else {
                    guard let message = response.message else { return completion(.failure(MockServicesError.withoutResponseObject)) }
                    completion(.failure(MockServicesError.serverResponseErrorWith(message: message)))
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Define the specific error message via view model

```
fileprivate enum HookErrorHandling {
    case withoutResponse
    case serverResponseErrorWith(errMessage: String)
    case fatelErrorWith(errMessage: String)
    case fatelError
}

extension HookErrorHandling {
    var message: String {
        switch self {
        case .withoutResponse:
            return "Server without response object"
        case .serverResponseErrorWith(let errMessage):
            return "Mock service response error with: \(errMessage)"
        case .fatelErrorWith(let errMessage):
            return "Fatel error with: \(errMessage)"
        case .fatelError:
            return "Encountered fatel Error"
        }
    }
}

final class ViewModel {
    
    let viewElement: Bindable<String?> = Bindable(nil)
    
    let errorMessage: Bindable<String?> = Bindable(nil)
    
    private var dataSource: DataRepositoryProtocol
    
    init(dataSource: DataRepositoryProtocol = DataRepositoryManager()) {
        self.dataSource = dataSource
    }
    
    func invokeMockService(_ parameter: MockParameter?, completionHandler handler: ((Result<String?, MockServicesError>) -> ())? = nil) {
        dataSource.queryMockServices(parameter) { [weak self] (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let dataString):
                if let dataValue = dataString {
                    self?.viewElement.value = dataValue
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                self?.feedingError(error)
            }
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Error Handling
    private func feedingError(_ error: MockServicesError) {
        switch error {
        case .withoutResponseObject:
            self.errorMessage.value = HookErrorHandling.withoutResponse.message
        case .serverResponseErrorWith(let message):
            self.errorMessage.value = HookErrorHandling.serverResponseErrorWith(errMessage: message).message
        case .fatelErrorWith(let message):
            self.errorMessage.value = HookErrorHandling.fatelErrorWith(errMessage: message).message
        case .fatelError:
            self.errorMessage.value = HookErrorHandling.fatelError.message
        }
    }
    
}
```

Feeding error message to view controller via bind

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    // MARK: - Property
    
    @IBOutlet weak var mockLabel: UILabel!
    
    var parameter: MockParameter?
    
    var viewModel: ViewModel = ViewModel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        triggerMockService()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        setupBinding()
    }

    // MARK: - Private Method
    
    private func setupBinding() {
        viewModel.viewElement.bind { [weak self] (successfulText) in
            self?.mockLabel.text = successfulText
        }
        
        viewModel.errorMessage.bind { [weak self] (errMessage) in
            self?.mockLabel.text = errMessage
        }
    }
    
    private func triggerMockService() {
        self.viewModel.invokeMockService(self.parameter)
    }

}
```

Above conception reference from [here](https://benoitpasquier.com/error-handling-swift-mvvm/).

And my casual practice a [demo](https://github.com/joshua24322/ErrorHandlingInMVVM).

Answer (score 0):

You just translate the data to an enum that you can feed to your view, like this:

```
enum LoginViewState {
    case `default`
    case loggingIn
    case loginFailed(LoginFailureReason)
}
enum LoginFailureReason {
    case invalidNameOrPassword
    case noInternet
    case unknown
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks if you any sample project git repository please share.